# JDBC returns an empty result set

Tags: sql, jdbc, resultset

ResultSet is empty although query should return whole table. Here is my code

```
try{
    Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
    con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost","somonjon","sa");
    con.setCatalog("ChatDBS");
    Statement stmt = null;
    String SQL = "SELECT * FROM Login_chat";
    stmt = con.createStatement();
    try{
    System.out.println("trying execute query");
    rs = stmt.executeQuery(SQL);
}
catch(SQLException ex){
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

this is the error message:
trying execute query
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The result set has no current row.

P.S. 
Okey guys I'm not sure is it important or not, but this codes is jButton1ActionPerformed event.

Comment: you need to call `rs.next()` before you can work with it.

Comment: Can you give full stacktrace pls

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name the problem is i can't do that, because the error gets in rs = stmt.executeQuery(SQL); line,

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you are not suppose to get this exception unless you are doing some operation over ResultSet like rs.next();

Regarding the problem is concerned, there could be two scenarios

1. You are not pointing to right database (catalog)
2. You have not committed the transaction in the database.

Answer (score 0):

You have to loop through rs.

```
String column1;
int column2;
while (rs.next()) {
  column1 = rs.getString("nameColumn1");
  column2 = rs.getInt("nameColumn2");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, in

```
String SQL = "SELECT * FROM Login_chat";
```

You have to add a ";".

```
String SQL = "SELECT * FROM Login_chat;";
```

Try with that!

Comment: thanks for answer, but still it didn't work, it definitely finds the DBS and Table, but in returns nothing.

Comment: No, that's wrong. Oracle won't accept the `;` as part of a SQL string through the JDBC interface.